# Unit testing PHP API connected to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, debugging, api

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql%20unit%20testing) didn't seem to help much so I'm posting.

I have a PHP API that makes MySQL inserts, updates, selects, etc. Basically whenever I change my PHP code to test it I have to use a fake dataset (because I don't want to corrupt my real data) and insert particular values, run the script, see if the necessary inserts and selects happen and then remove all the values I just added and restore the database etc, and repeat as I debug. It's doable but it takes FOREVER.

any ideas for a better method? I'm all ears...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same database for both production and testing?

If yes, switch to a separate db just for the test data.  After the test suite runs, you can just drop the entire database.  Do a bulk restore with clean test data using MySQL's command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is a definite candidate for a staging/QA environment. Then you can keep a .sql file lying around that provides you with your dummy data set, and can rapidly nuke it/tinker with it.

If you are looking for ways to implement this, I recommend mirroring your production environment in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Work with three database environments: `Development`, `Testing/Staging` and `Production`.

Naturally, the schema in production should be the same as testing/staging, and development as well, minus the changes that you're actually working on in dev.

In line with the above, have three config files for your database connections. Even if you're working locally and need to have both development and stating databases in one machine, it should be okay, but if you can separate them all (provided you work in a corporate environment that can afford it or if you at least have other boxes to deploy as testing servers)

With that kind of setup implemented, all you really ever have to do is to just make sure that dev changes are propagated to staging, and that you have three config files. Preferably, have three separate folders for your code as well. If you are working with windows, then you can create a batch file to automatically create backups in staging before overwriting the files with your dev files (minus the configs; do that manually if you make changes)

Then when you need to test something emulating what the production environment should be, you'll just have to run the batch file then access your staging host to test.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing as you.

I found the best solution to codes with PDO connections, using PHPUnit and the class [PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html).

You have to code two methods: getConnection() and getDataset(). You can set your own connection, and the dataset could be a XML file, with some static data (or real subqueries). That methodology will truncate the selected table, insert the values in your dataset, then you set your model layer connection to getConnection() and all the operations it would be operated in the static database.
Then, you can assert tables, assert datasets, assert number of results, all to compare the success of your operations in the database.

At the end, PHPUnit will restore your database to the original state.

There is a good and funny presentation [here](http://matthewturland.com/slides/phpunit-db/) that illustrate some methods allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question concerning changes to PHP Code.

My questions, why are you even running unit tests against your database every time there is a change to PHP code?

Have you not written your code in Layers (Multi-tier)?

If you have, then replace the database with an in-memory datastore.